# Trying to make a fish diversity map using ArcGIS 10.7.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, biology, species

I'm relatively new using ArcGIS. I want to make a fish species richness map (or fish diversity map; essentially tells you how many fish species are in each grid cell). Things I did so far:

- Obtained the fish data (they are hundreds of layers; each layer contains one fish species)
- I merged all the fish layers (because I want to make a 10*10 km grid)
- Made a 10*10 km grid (or fishnet)
- Spatial joined the grid to the merged fish layer (problematic, I often end up getting null value in the attribute table and I'm not sure how do I count the number of species in each cell using field calculator or other functions; species description info in the attribute table are in text format).

[image: The attribute table of the spatial_join layer, joined the fish data and the grid layer]

Ideally, I'd like to make a map just like this (https://biodiversitymapping.org/index.php/usa-fish/).

How do I use the spatial join function in Arc to show the number of species per grid (or species richness per grid)? Also, is it possible to add in a new field in the attribute table which can count number of species (for instance, if there are 3 different species in one grid, the new field will show the value of 3, something like that)?

Again, my goal is to make a map that can show number of species per grid cell.

Comment: Spatial join isn't the only way to establish relationships between geometric objects. It's not even the best way. You have the whole Overlay toolset avaliable -- Intersect, Union, or Identity (with an Advanced license) will do most of the work for you.

Comment: Hi Vince, thanks for your reply, as for the join tool, are you referring to the "add join" (would that join a table to a layer instead of join a layer to layer?)?

Comment: I can't see the link to the map example (maybe because I am in Canada). I think you want to do a union rather than a spatial join. Alternatively, you could convert the data to rasters, assign the value of 1 to each grid cell for each fish species layer, then you could use the raster calculator to add the layers together.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the reply, I have updated the link, now it should work (the left one is the map I want). I contacted the original creator of those maps, he said he cannot remember the details about how to make those maps (he made those maps 6 years ago) but he mentioned that he did not use any raster data (raster data can result in some weird pattern for the fish diversity map); so he did all analyses in vector form. Now I'm even more confused as I don't know a way of counting each number of species per polygon using purely on vector analysis.

Comment: He also said that he did analyses on each species individually, and then he stacked them together to make the richness map. Now I'm looking for some techniques to be sure that species in one watershed were not being counted in adjacent watersheds.